# Send message to MassTransit Saga in ASP.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit, saga

I have a simple saga configuration in Asp.Net Core applicaiton:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ISagaRepository<Request>, InMemorySagaRepository<Request>>();
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddSagaStateMachine<RequestStateMachine, Request>();
    x.AddRequestClient<IRequestCreated>();
    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
    }));
});
```

If later I send message to Saga over `IRequestClient<IRequestCreated>`:

```cs
var client = context.RequestServices.GetService<IRequestClient<IRequestCreated>>();
var response = await client.GetResponse<RequestCreatedResponse>(new
{
    CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ClientId = 1,
});
```

all works fine. But if I try same thing over `IBus`:

```cs
var mtbus = context.RequestServices.GetService<IBus>();
await mtbus.Send<IRequestCreated>(new
{
    CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ClientId = 1,
});
```

I get error `A convention for the message type Sample.AspNetCore.Host.Saga.IRequestCreated was not found`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above, because no service address is specified for the request client, it is publishing the request. Which gets routed to the consumer.

In your failing case, you're using Send, which without an address needs to know where to send the message. The only fallback is the convention, which isn't configured. If you want the same behavior, and honestly, since you're publishing a `RequestCreated` event, you should call Publish as well.